# Bash script: Looping through directories over SSH and downloading them to local machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

I'm trying to write a bash script that:

- Loops through all the directories in a folder over an SSH server
- Downloads a file (titled say, "foo") inside each of these folders to a local machine.

At the moment, I have:

```
ssh username@server "for dir in ~/directoryname/*; (... something here!); done"
```

I don't think I can use scp while I'm accessing the SSH server, however. Is there a way I can loop through and download everything here?

Comment: Duplicate on another network: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107122/downloading-files-over-ssh-based-on-a-list-of-filenames

Comment: FYI, StackSnippets are only for HTML and JavaScript. For regular code formatting, use the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running `scp` remotely would work only if the remote server has access to your own system.  let's assume it doesn't.

you could do it in two steps:

```
ssh username@server "... some script that just echos the paths ..." > log
for line in $(<log); do scp username@server:$line ./dir/$line; done
```

or you could investigate `rsync` which is extremely powerful.  it has `--include` and `--exclude` options which would allow you to do something like:

```
rsync -av username@server:~/somepath/ ./somepath/ [--exclude/--include flags]
```

Comment: Another common pattern is piping a tarball. `ssh "$server" 'tar -C /source/directory-name .' | tar -C /dest/directory-name -x`.

Comment: BTW, `for line in $(<log)` is buggy. Use BashFAQ #1 patterns (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) instead. Otherwise, you'll have trouble with filenames with spaces, filenames with glob literals, etc.

Comment: (also, one `scp` instance per file is insanely inefficient -- for any significant number of files, one would at least want to use ControlMaster to reuse a single connection; see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing)

Comment: (with respect to the piping-a-tarball approach, `tar` can accept a list of files on stdin, so one can use logic in `find` or such to filter).

Comment: i'm fully aware of the caveats shell-wise and performance wise with the snippets i posted.  his request seems like a dirty one-off that doesn't need to be kept around.

Comment: Like any other answer on StackOverflow, content becomes part of the knowledge base and thus effectively lives forever. Taking care and paying attention to maintaining an answer many people will (presumably) use makes just as much sense as taking care and paying attention to a script one person will use over an extended period, and for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that script is an argument passed to ssh, and is run on the remote machine, which means you can't easily reference your own machine in order to tell it where to copy the files to.

You could try a bash script that runs locally to fetch the directory structure you're searching, and use scp to copy over any that you're interested in retrieving.

Or, depending on the sizes involved, scp over all of `directoryname/`, and get what you want from there.